# SAS Adding Across Rows

Tags: sas

Attached is an example of a dataset where the ID# column has some values that are identical, but the Dollar Amount column has different values for the same ID#. How can I go about adding the Dollar Amount across rows where the ID# is identical, and essentially create a summary row for that ID#? The list is much longer than this, so specifying each ID# isn't an option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are SQL options as well, but this is how one would do a running total/summation in a data step.

```
data have;
input id $1. dollar_amount 8.;
format dollar_amount dollar25.;
cards;
1   24
2   53
2   67
3   35
4   86
5   245
6   353
6   56
7   21
;
run;

proc sort data=have noequals; /*Only run if not already sorted*/
by id;
run;

data want(drop=dollar_amount);
set have;
by id;
if first.id then dollar_total = .;
format dollar_total dollar25.;
dollar_total + dollar_amount;
if last.id then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PROC SQL and want the actual summary row within the input data (I thought that was what you were asking), here are simple data steps that uses a flag to identify the sum row:

```
data have;
input id $1. dollar_amount 8.;
format dollar_amount dollar25.;
cards;
1   24
2   53
2   67
3   35
4   86
5   245
6   353
6   56
7   21
;
run;

proc means data = have noprint;
    by id;
    var dollar_amount;
    output out=sum_data (drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=dollar_amount ;
run;

data sum_data; set sum_data;
    sum_row=1;
run;

data final;
    set have sum_data;
run;

proc sort data = final;
    by id sum_row;
run;
```

If you just want an output data set that generates sums by unique ID, then just use something like:

```
proc means data = have noprint;
    by id;
    var dollar_amount;
    output out = want (drop=_type_ _freq_) sum=dollar_amount_sum;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

And the PROC SQL equivalent...

```
data have;
input id $1. dollar_amount 8.;
format dollar_amount dollar25.;
cards;
1   24
2   53
2   67
3   35
4   86
5   245
6   353
6   56
7   21
;
run;


proc Sql;
create table want as
  Select 
ID,
sum(dollar_amount) as dollar_amount format dollar25.

  from have
group by ID
  ;
quit;
```

[image]